# libgdx gdx-setup.jar Build failed

Tags: java, android, maven, libgdx

I have problem with resolving dependencies. Have you guys had similar issue? Any ideas?
thanks in advance

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: 

    A problem occurred configuring root project 'test'.
        > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'. 
        > Could not find org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT. 
       Searched in the following locations:
        _https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/robovm/robovm-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml 
        _https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/robovm/robovm-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/robovm-gradle-plugin-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom 
        _https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/robovm/robovm-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/robovm-gradle-plugin-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
        _https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/robovm/robovm-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml 
        _https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/robovm/robovm-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/robovm-gradle-plugin-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom 
        _https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/robovm/robovm-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/robovm-gradle-plugin-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
       Required by: :test:unspecified
```

(I've added underscore in links to get it posted in here.)

it works when I uncheck iOS subproject... Have no idea how to fix it

Comment: Should be fixed already:https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2921

Comment: Well, I just got the latest version and it's back.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using a libGDX project with libGDX version 1.5.4.

In your build.gradle file look for something like:

classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' and change it to: classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-beta-04'

Do the same for: roboVMVersion = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' and change it to: roboVMVersion = '1.0.0-beta-04'

This should work otherwise try changing both to: 1.0.0-beta-01.

After this it should ask you to sync your project, click sync now!

Hope this helps!
Here are some helpful links:

https://github.com/robovm/robovm-gradle-plugin#robovm-gradle-plugin
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/news.html

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using the latest version of Android Studio 4.0.0, if your **Generate** fails in libGDX it says

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

[image]

Don't worry you need to downgrade Gradle version to 6.0 by dragging the file you created in libGDX into Android Studio, then going to **Gradle Script> gradle-wrapper.properties**
And change

distributionUrl = https : //services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-zip.zip

**change into**

distributionUrl = https : //services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0-all.zip

[image]

*Please note you will also need to install java jdk 8!*

This worked for me, I had to spend a lot of time including uninstalling Android Studio but it didn't work at all. From above experience is how I got it solved very quickly and inexpensively!